# why cant I write a windows filepath like this in golang ？

Tags: windows, go, path

I am trying to read a file on windows in golang. The path is `C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\1.jpeg`, and I write like this:

```golang
filepath := "C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\1.jpeg"
```

This declaration and assignment is illegal by itself as it is marked red in vscode. I've been reading about how golang uses filepath package to handle path issues, but it does not cover the situation where `\` is the separator.

By the way, if a `\` is added after each `\` in the statement above, it works.

Comment: Use backticks/backquotes, i.e. `\`foo\bar\``, instead of double quotes, i.e. `"foo\bar"` for the string. Or use two backslashes `"\\"`. A backslash in an *interpreted string* (double quoted string) indicates an escape sequence. And just fyi single quotes `'...'` are for *rune* literals, i.e. single-character literals, not **strings**.

Comment: As alsays, it helps [to read the docs](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals).

Answer (score 3):

I don't use vscode but I know `\` is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

And there is no meaning for \U, \l, and \D.

So you should use,

```golang
filepath := "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Downloads\\1.jpeg"
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively use backticks for a raw string where nothing is escaped:

```
path := `C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\1.jpeg`
```